# Basic question on limit of a positive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\{h_n\}$ be a real positive sequence so that $h_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. To characterize how faster $h_n$ converges to zero, assume $nh^5\to c_h$, where $c_h>0$ is a constant.

Can I conclude that for any $5>\delta>0$, $nh^\delta\to \infty$, and for any $\theta>5$, $nh^\theta\to 0$?

**My argument**

I thinks this is the case. Without loss of generality, take $\delta=4$. Since $h_n\to 0$, then
$$nh_n^4=\frac{nh_n^5}{h}\to\infty.$$

On the other hand, take $\theta=6$. Then $nh^6=nh^5h\to 0$.

Can you give me feedback on this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This looks correct to me

Comment: @YuliaV Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @YuliaV I agree. For this reason I wrote "without loss of generality".